# ERROR Appenders contains an invalid element or attribute "NoSql"

Tags: java, mongodb, log4j2

I am getting ERROR Appenders contains an invalid element or attribute "NoSql", when I am trying to log message through log4j2 using NoSql appender. I have used below jar file in my classpath
log4j-core-2.9.1.jar
log4j-api-2.9.1.jar
mongo-java-driver-3.5.0.jar
log4j-nosql-2.9.1.jar
rpa-apis_1.0.jar
xercesImpl-2.9.0.jar
disruptor-3.3.7.jar

when I am running this java project with Eclipse, its working fine. But after creating runnable jar, I am getting error and no log going into MongoDB. I am using java -jar abc.jar to execute runnable jar. I have gone with Google, but not found something related. Providing Related Image file.
Please help to resolve the issue.[image][image]
[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKZqt.png)
[image]

Comment: Be sure to have all your dependencies when running you jar outside of eclipse

Comment: As Sown in image, All the dependency jar is already added on class path. So I have no clue, even if I running this in eclipse environment, its working fine.Only issue with runnable jar.

Answer (score 0):

This error can happen when a Plugin cannot be found. From the sound of things you are building an uber jar. When building an uber jar with Log4j 2.x you need to mrege the Log4j2Plugins.dat files that are present in each jar. This `[Stackoverflow question][1]` provides a solution for that. You can also try Log4j2 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT. It packages the plugin descriptors in classes that are located using java.util.ServiceLoader. So long as the shading process supports merging multiple implementations of a service it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

This error can happen when a Plugin cannot be found. From the sound of things you are building an uber jar and either the plugin descriptor can't be found or the plugin class can't be located. When building an uber jar with Log4j 2.x you need to mrege the Log4j2Plugins.dat files that are present in each jar. This `[Stackoverflow question][1]` provides a solution for that. You can also try Log4j2 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT. It packages the plugin descriptors in classes that are located using java.util.ServiceLoader. So long as the shading process supports merging multiple implementations of a service it should work fine.

It should also be obvious but the relevant jars for the nosql and mongodb appender support would also be have to be included.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Are you want to say about Log4j 3.0.0 jar version or some thing else. or if possible please provide insight on Merging of Log4j2Plugins.dat, I have not much knowledge on this.

Comment: Hi,
After adding below line in java code, I am able to execute runnable jar successfully and it also adding data in MongoDb.

PluginManager.addPackage("org.apache.logging.log4j.nosql.appender");

Thanks to all support

Answer (score 0):

log4j2 doc Configuration Syntax, you can also add packages config to log4j2.xml.
Log4j – Configuring Log4j 2
[enter link description here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#ConfigurationSyntax)